# Is there an area where users can find out how to be good reviewers?

Tags: discussion

So I have been able to review posts for a while now and I like to think I've gotten pretty good at it. When I started however, that was a different story.

For the first few, I wasn't sure what was considered a good or bad question, so I'm sure there were a few bad eggs that got through.

Is there a space where a new reviewer can go and learn what it is to be a good reviewer and look at what makes a good/bad post or is the "Learn As You Go" method sufficient?

Comment: There’s a log of all reviews in a given queue. Select **Recent reviews** from the /review page, then select the **History** tab. Takes you to, e.g. http://ux.stackexchange.com/review/first-posts/history Not always clear how a particular reviewer behaved, but it might be useful to see how other people are reviewing. I find it especially helpful to look at reviews I skipped, and see what the outcome was.

Comment: [What are the guidelines for reviewing?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/155538) may be of help.

Comment: @alexwlchan: Pretty sure only 10k users and diamonds can see others' review histories.

Comment: @NathanTuggy You’re right, I’d missed that. But you can still see reviews you skipped (there’s a checkbox at the bottom of the page), and look at them to see how other users handled that item.